# CSS transitions across pixel distance

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I'm trying to get a CSS transition to work for when I change a div's location. It's a horizontal form that pops up from the bottom of the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="admin-bar hidden" id="quick-access">
    <div class="admin-bar-inner">
        // form content
```

**CSS:**

```
.page-content .admin-bar {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-content .hidden {
    bottom: -140px;
}

#quick-access {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

**JS:**

```
// to view the form
$('#raiseForm').on( "click",function() {
    $("#quick-access").removeClass("hidden");
});

// on submit or cancel
$("#quick-access").addClass("hidden");
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting the transition at all, just the section pop in and out. I chose to do it with adding-removing a class because that's the easiest way to make it responsive.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Weird, I tried your code in a codepen and it animates for me correctly. When you inspect it, are you sure your transitions aren't being overwritten anywhere by other rules?

Comment: Yes it was being overridden. Use of the word "hidden" wasn't original enough and it was conflicting with a similar class in bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When thinking up class names, ensure what you're using actually is unique. "hidden" was being overridden by a class within bootstrap.css:

```
.hidden {
    display:none !important
}
```

Changing hidden to something else solved the problem.